# Android: Show custom font in Graphical Layout tool

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got custom fonts loading in my application just fine, but since I can't see their position until I load up the application it's taking an exorbitant amount of time to get my display just right.

Is there any way to get the Graphical Layout tool in eclipse to display a custom font so I can position it there before running the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, but the answer is NO

Answer (score 7):

The eclipse layout editor uses the fonts provided by, and registered in, the android sdk platforms you have installed on your dev box.  Therefore if you really must see your custom/non-standard font in the eclipse layout editor you can fiddle with the relevant platform font registry (see <android-sdk>\platforms\android-XX\data\fonts\system_fonts.xml).

I typically redefine the monospace and serif families (which I don't generally use) to reference the custom fonts I am using in the app.  You can then reference the monospace and serif typefaces from your xml layouts and they'll be rendered in the eclipse layout editor using your custom/non-standard font.

DISCLAIMER: If you do this bad things can happen.