# Include external font so it is rendered in eclipse xml preview

Tags: android, eclipse, fonts, textview

I'm including external font assets in my android app, however, eclipse is not able to render them in the xml preview.

When I include the fonts in the app (put the ttf in /assets/fonts folder) and set my textview fonts dynamically with the code:

```
mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fontfilename.ttf");
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textview.setTypeface(mFont);
```

the text is rendered correctly with the font in the app on my device or emulator, however I haven't a clue on how to get eclipse to render them in the xml preview. I've tried extending the TextView class:

```
public class ExTextView extends TextView {

private static final Typeface MY_FONT_01 = Typeface.create("mfont-01", 0); //, Typeface.BOLD);
private static final Typeface MY_FONT_02 = Typeface.create("mfont-02", 0); //, Typeface.NORMAL);

public ExTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    if (getTypeface().equals(MY_FONT_01)) {
        Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/myfont01.ttf");
        setTypeface(mFont);
        setPadding(0, (int) (-0.9f * getTextSize()), 0, (int) (-0.2f * getTextSize()));
        setTextSize(0x00000001, (int)48);
    } else if (getTypeface().equals(MY_FONT_02)) {
        Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/myfont02.ttf");
        setTypeface(mFont);
        setPadding(0, (int) (-0.5f * getTextSize()), 0, (int) (-0.5f * getTextSize()));
        setTextSize(0x00000001, (int) 24);
    }
}
}
```

and putting this in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.extendedtextview.ExTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="mfont-01"
    android:text="ExTextView-01" />

<com.example.extendedtextview.ExTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="mfont-02"
    android:text="ExTextView-02" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but the fonts are not rendering according to what is declared in ExTextView.java. I know this is going about this the hard way for this particularly simple app, but in a more complex scenario, this kind of structure might be useful, so I'd like to figure out how to get it working.

When I try to run the app I get the error in logcat:

```
04-03 11:38:08.149: E/AndroidRuntime(689): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.extendedtextview.ExTextView
```

Any suggestions or hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Show custom font in Graphical Layout tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878732/android-show-custom-font-in-graphical-layout-tool)

Comment: yes, you are probably right. So it might possible to get eclipse to display the font, but it would required messing with some sdk files.